# Fix an element to bottom after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a reverse scrolling webiste

```
<div class="end"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="ruler"><div class="currentheight">asd</div></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="content">

<div class="high" id="high"><img src="placeholder.png"></img><h3>1.9km –  THIS HIGH! </h3></div>
<div class="washington"><a id="washington" class="btn btn-2 btn-2c" href="#high">Keep Going</a><img src="placeholder.png"></img><h3>0.15km – Washington Monument  </h3></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="ep">
<a href="#washington" class="btn btn-2 btn-2c">START</a>
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>content</h2>
</div>


$(function() {  $('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height() - $(window).height());});
```

The element currentheight is verticaly aligned at the bottom of the ruler section - how to fix it to the bottom of the page when the user scrolls up, so it would stay always visible?

FIDDLE :  https://jsfiddle.net/koteva/5ug7pkte/

Comment: which element you wanna fix to `bottom`?

Comment: `.ruler: { position: fixed }` then you need to fix the wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class "fixed" to the currentheight element when window scrolls up the element. You need to get the height of the window and bottom offset of element. You can achieve this like this:

CSS:

```
.currentheight.fixed {position:fixed;bottom:38px;left:0px;background:rgba(0,0,8,1);width:calc(33% - 42px);}
```

JS:

```
//to start at bottom of page
$(function () { $('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height() - $(window).height()); });

// Store the bottom offset of currentheight element so that we don't recalculate at every scroll event
var elemBottomOffset;

//scrolling animations
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); var target = this.hash; var $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ 'scrollTop': $target.offset().top },
         1200, 'easeInOutQuart', function () { window.location.hash = target; });
    });
    // Calculate the bottom offset of currentheight element only once
    elemBottomOffset= $('.currentheight').offset().top + $('.currentheight').outerHeight();
});

$.fn.calc_height = function () {

    var window_scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var window_scroll_top_cm = window_scroll_top * 0.026458333;
    $('.currentheight').html(window_scroll_top_cm.toFixed(2) + ' cm');
    // Code to add fixed class based on window scrolling
    if (window_scroll_top + $(window).height() < elemBottomOffset)
        $('.currentheight').addClass('fixed');
    else
        $('.currentheight').removeClass('fixed');
};

//counter that needs to be positioned
$(function () {
    $.fn.calc_height();
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        $.fn.calc_height();
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ug7pkte/6/

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/5ug7pkte/1/

```
.ruler{
    background:rgba(0,0,8,1);
    position:fixed; // added
}

.main{background:rgba(0,0,0,0) url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQW9XmL6F5hmpPd8iwdBXJ4-UrProCpCnM6fcxhZFYvMy7FVX_JK6QDig') repeat-y scroll 0 0 / 8cm auto;height: 70470cm;
    margin-left:257px; // added
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make menu fixed at the bottom and add some padding bottom to body and check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5ug7pkte/2/)

```
body{
        padding-bottom: 300px;
}
.fixedBottom{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```